# Python: deleting large data

Tags: python

I have a large dataset that I am dealing with in Python. It is hierarchical just like DOM. I have a root node object, and from that object all the other objects emanate.

SO, if I just do `del obj` where `obj` is root node, will the entire hierarchy be gone immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Immediately", no. The garbage collector will sweep it up next run, assuming there are no other references to that object.

Comment: Assuming there are no other references to the object you delete, you will no longer be able to reach it (so it will be "gone for *you*".) The memory will be freed by the garbage collector when it gets around to it.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html states that you can force the GC to release unreferenced objects with gc.collect()